# Select all records of a List<T> relationship into Results<T>?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm binding a table view to a collection of `Results<Person>` this result set can be filtered but normally it is not. The problem is that when I try to bind - say; `person.children` to the table view which is of type `List<Person>`. If I don't filter it, I don't get a `Results<Person>` type, so I need to have two different properties to store the dataset for the table. One for `Results`, one for `List`.

My question is... is there a way to return all records from a `List` as `Results`? Something similar to `.all()`? I have tried to use an empty NSPredicate, but this is not allowed and a property name must be specified. I want my function to be generic enough that it can be called on any List to obtain all Results. I don't want to have to specify say... `.filter("firstName != ''")` just to get all the results.

I have currently implemented something like this... But I'm curious if there's a better way.

```
extension List {
    func all() -> Results<T> {
        let primaryKey = T.primaryKey() ?? "id"
        return self.filter("\(primaryKey) != ''")
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Looks like this implementation of All will not work for Objects with a primary key of type Int. Is there anyway to check an object's primary key type?

Answer (score 2):

Using `TRUEPREDICATE` seems to work!

```
extension List {
    /// Returns an Results object for all Objects in the List.
    func all() -> Results<T> {
        return self.filter("TRUEPREDICATE")
    }
}
```

Comment: This will probably be your best bet in the short-term, though we're working on a `RealmCollectionType` protocol that will make things easier

Comment: We now have a PR pending review which introduces `RealmCollectionType`.

Comment: Nice! We look forward to checking it out.